# How to delete a d3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to delete the D3 pie chart. I have created the pie chart but what I want to do is on some button click I want to delete the pie chart and want to re-draw the new pie chart with some new data. I didn't find any help from the documentation of D3's website. I am sharing the code for drawing the pie chart below.

```
   var w =300;
   var h =300;
   var r =150;
   data = [{"label": "joy", "value": 20},
        {"label": "fear", "value": 20},
        {"label": "anger", "value": 20},
        {"label": "disgust", "value": 20},
        {"label": "sadness", "value": 20}] 
  var colorArray = ['#f6cf31', '#7e53a3', '#f8522a', '#3cbf55', '#00a7de']
    var vis = d3.select(".chart-holder")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .data([data])
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(r);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });

    var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "slice");

    arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colorArray[i];
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the id of the pie chart, you can then use it later to remove the element:

```
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
        .data(pie)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr("id", "mypiechart");

...

d3.select("#mypiechart").remove();
```

Comment: as i  a have told you that i need to re draw again.But when i apply this function d3.select("#mypiechart").remove(); it actually remove that div so in this way i can not redraw again.Please suggest something which can be use for redraw.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it my self, well anyway thanks @ilivewithian.
The soultion is

```
  var vis = angular.element('svg');
    //   var vis = d3.select(".chart-holder").selectAll("svg");
    vis.remove();
```

Remove is actually javascript default function to remove any element.
So i get the svg element from the div i bind for pie chart.And removed the svg element.

And then i redraw it,using the same techinique i used for drawing the pie chart first time.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the exit method for d3 data is working the same way like update, per documentation
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

you have first to assign the data to the path then remove it for updating

```
var path = svg.selectAll('path')
.data(pie(data));

path.enter()
.append('path')
.attr('d', arc)
.attr('class', '.path')
.attr('id', function(d) {
    return d.data.key;
})
.attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
})

// exit
path.exit().remove();
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to simply set a new value for your data variable and the chart can update from this.

```
function setData(){
  data = [{"label": "new", "value": 50},
         {"label": "old", "value": 50}]

  myChart.update();
  };
```

Pulled from the GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki/Sample-chart-%28your-first-nvd3-chart!%29

Comment: please can you elaborate this little bit.

Comment: it is not helpful and i ma unable to understand that.

Comment: This information is straight from their documentation, you can remove the chart and redraw it if you like but it is better to simply update the data and then call the update() function so that it can realize the new data added. You can see more of the code at the link provided.